# Apply function to specific elements

Tags: jquery

I know this is elementary stuff, but I just can't figure it out...

How do I apply the css changes to multiple elements? At the moment, it's only working for the first, but showing no errors.

```
function elemInit(){

    var elem1 = jQ('#elem1');
    var elem2 = jQ('#elem2');

    jQ(elem1, elem2).each(function(){
        jQ(this).css({
            'margin-left': '-' + jQ(this).width()/2 + 'px'
        });
    });

};

elemInit();
```

`jQ` is to ensure there's no conflict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery selectors work like CSS selectors, also `css` method uses `each` method internally, you can code:

```
jQ('#elem1, #elem2').css('marginLeft', function(i, oldMarginLeft) {
     return '-' + jQ(this).width()/2 + 'px';
});
```

Comment: Interesting approach. I forgot about declaring a function for the value, and had no idea about css's default each method. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
var jQelem1and2 = jQ('#elem1, #elem2');

jQelem1and2.each(function(){
    jQ(this).css({
        'margin-left': '-' + jQ(this).width()/2 + 'px'
    });
});
```

Or did I miss something?

Comment: @verism Great. I would suggest undefined's approach. It does something similar to this (internally), but looks a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you used to join the two jQuery objects -- `$($obj1, $obj2)` -- is incorrect; it does [something entirely different](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1).

Apart from the other solutions that work by directly matching the elements you need to, the general solution is to use [`.add`](http://api.jquery.com/add/):

```
$obj1.add($obj2).each(...)
```

And finally, there's really no need for `.each` here -- `.css` directly would work as well.

Comment: Thanks for the info - I tried add(), copied from another example, but without success.

Comment: You tried `elem1.add(elem2)` in the function above and it didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var elem1 = '#elem1';
var elem2 = '#elem2';  
jQ(elem1, elem2).each(function(){
    jQ(this).css({
        'margin-left': '-' + jQ(this).width()/2 + 'px'
    });
});
```